# using a function inside a sub (VBA using Word and Excel)

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a question about using a private function inside a private sub (command button).

It doesn't return any errors... nor does it do anything. When I press the command button in Word doc, it is supposed to form rows and import data from an Excel worksheet until the last row in Excel, which is what I'm trying to get the function to do - find the last row in the worksheet.

If you can look at my code and let me know if you know why it won't work, I'd appreciate it. Do I need to have the function inside the Private Sub commandbutton_2_Click()? Thank you in advance.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim tbl As Table
Dim row As row

Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(2)

Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
On Error Resume Next

Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("S:\Electro-Protocol\Mot_Protocols\" & TextBox1 & ".xls")
Dim lastRow As Integer

lastRow = GetLastRow(objExcel, exWb)
ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Columns.DistributeWidth

For counter = 1 To lastRow
tbl.Rows.Add
tbl.cell(counter, 1).Range.Text = exWb.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(counter, 1)
tbl.cell(counter, 2).Range.Text = exWb.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(counter, 2)
tbl.cell(counter, 3).Range.Text = exWb.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(counter, 3)
tbl.cell(counter, 4).Range.Text = exWb.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(counter, 4)
tbl.cell(counter, 5).Range.Text = exWb.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(counter, 5)
tbl.cell(counter, 6).Range.Text = exWb.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(counter, 6)
Next counter

End Sub

Private Function GetLastRow(ByVal objExcel As Excel.Application, ByVal exWb As Excel.Workbook) As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = 0

With exWb.Sheets("Tabelle1")
If objExcel.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
    lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                  After:=.Range("A1"), _
                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                  MatchCase:=False).row
Else
    lastRow = 1
End If
End With
End Function
```

Comment: For us to answer "why it won't work" you first need to tell us *how it didn't work*.  What happened?

Comment: Where is it erroring? Have you stepped through the code line by line to see what happens? On what line does it stop doing what you would expect it to do?

Comment: I said it didn't do anything (didn't return any error either), as if I didn't press the command button. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @roryap they said it didn't do anything.

Comment: Please remove `On Error Resume Next`. It won't show you any errors if that command is in your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before `End Function` you need to do this:

```
GetLastRow = lastRow
```

else the function does not return a value.

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks so much helping out a vba newbie. One more question - do you maybe know how to successfully quit Excel after everything? I tried putting......Excel.Application.Quit...... before End Sub AND before End Function and they both give me "Run-time error: Automoation error, The message filter indicated that the application is busy."

Comment: Sure. `objExcel.Quit` is what you need.

Comment: I thought it didn't work when I tried it before... Now it works great. Thank you so much!